# PHP File hosting

Tags: php, image, file, hosting

i need your help for my website http://usb-online.fr . It's a php file host website and here's a part of the download thing :

```
header("Content-Type: $mime; name=\"$fichier\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: $taille");
header('Content-Description: Fichier hebergé par usb-online.fr');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fichier\"");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

ob_clean();
flush();
log_download($file,$infos['auteur'],$taille);
bunzip2($path);
```

If you try this url :
http://usb-online.fr/file-download-822MjYzMg.html
You will see a download box is open and the image is not displayed, that's what i want.
But it the user do `<img src="http://usb-online.fr/file-download-822MjYzMg.html"/>` in a website, he can display the image and my server becomes busy. i don't want to allow this, how can i do?
http://usb-online.fr/file-download-822MjYzMg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do what you want. If you allow a browser to access a URL, there's no way to control what it does with the data at the remote end.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called 'Hotlinking' there are several ways to disable it.

Here is one described which kind of applies to your situation; http://safalra.com/programming/php/prevent-hotlinking/ otherwise there is a lot to be found on Google.

Comment: They use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. I thought it wasn't reliable.

Comment: I can't do like they did, cause the link can go onto forums or stuff like this and they should be able to download the file. So i can't say : If there is a referer don't show the file.

Answer (score 1):

Add a nonce to your session.  Use that nonce as part of the URL for the image you want to protect. When you get a request for the image, only reply if the user's nonce is provided.

A nonce is essentially some random bits, could be a number, could be a string.  Nonces are often used to prevent CSRF attacks.  In this case you create a new, random, nonce and store it in the user's session.  Let's use "asdfgh" as a nonce for this example.  Then use something like

```
<img src="yoururl.php?n=asdfgh">
```

In yoururl.php, check that the value of n from the request matches the nonce stored in the user's session.  No match, no image.

Comment: I'm sorry but im not english and don't really understand 'nonce'. Can you explain me a little more in details what you mean?

Comment: I added an explanation of nonce to the answer.  Does it help?

Comment: See his answer to Gerald Versluis, he wants to allow linking to the file from external sites, so there's no session.

Comment: But he can redirect users to a "your file is ready to download, click here to start" page (ala download.com/hotfile.com/etc) where he initializes a session and continues with Walrii's suggestion.

Comment: Ye it seems it will be necessary to create an intermediate page 'click here to download your file' like all file hosters do. I wanted to avoid this step cause my site is here to  be really fast in all steps (otherwise he is useless as there are many other websites that do the same things better).